# How to display and hide links and nodes when clicking on a node in D3 Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, force-layout

I am trying to follow this D3 Javascript link: > http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130 to understand how the click event works. What I am trying to do is when clicking on the blue node, the other two nodes and their links should display. When I click on the same node again, the two nodes and their links must hide. If I click on one of the other two nodes, nothing should happen.

Here is the JSON file:

```
{
"nodes": [
    {
        "name": "Node1",
        "group": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "Node2",
        "group": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Node3",
        "group": 1
    }
],
"links": [
    {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 1,
        "value": 2
    },
    {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 2,
        "value": 2
    }
]
}
```

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<style>

.node {
stroke: #fff;
stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
stroke: #999;
stroke-opacity: .6;
}

</style>
<body>
<p>Are you there!!!</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
height = 500;

d3.json("sample.json", function(error, graph) {

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
force
.nodes(graph.nodes)
.links(graph.links)
.start();

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
.data(graph.links)
.enter().append("line")
.attr("class", "link")
.style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
.data(graph.nodes)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("class", "node")
.attr("r", 5)
.style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
.call(force.drag);

node.append("title")
.text(function(d) { return d.name; });

force.on("tick", function() {
link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
.attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
.attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
.attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
.attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Could anyone help me solve this issue please. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can break down the steps required to toggle on/off the visibility of a node's neighbors/edges by clicking that node as follows:

1. You need to class links based on the names of the sources/targets, and give nodes ids based on their names. This makes determining which nodes/links to toggle trivial.
2. You need to store whether or not each node is currently "active," which you can use to determine whether or not you should hide/show the node's neighbors.
3. You need to add an `on("click", function(){ ... })` to each node.

I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdml/Q7uNz/) that demonstrates this approach. The main points to highlight are that, first, I create a dictionary to map node names to the names of their neighbors, which makes determining which links to show/hide easy:

```
// Set up dictionary of neighbors
var node2neighbors = {};
for (var i =0; i < json.nodes.length; i++){
    var name = json.nodes[i].name;
    node2neighbors[name] = json.links.filter(function(d){
            return d.source.name == name || d.target.name == name;
        }).map(function(d){
            return d.source.name == name ? d.target.name : d.source.name;
        });
}
```

To get the names of the neighbors of a node `n`, I am first filtering all the links that include `n`, and then extracting the name of the node that is not `n` in each of those links.

Next, here's the logic performed when you click on a node. I'm using an array of nodes to keep track of the nodes we want to toggle on/off (the OP said this behavior should only apply for the blue node `"Node1"`):

```
var clickableNodes = ["Node1"];
nodes.filter(function(n){ return clickableNodes.indexOf(n.name) != -1; })
        // Determine if current node's neighbors and their links are visible
        var active   = n.active ? false : true // toggle whether node is active
        , newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;

        // Extract node's name and the names of its neighbors
        var name     = n.name
        , neighbors  = node2neighbors[name];

        // Hide the neighbors and their links
        for (var i = 0; i < neighbors.length; i++){
            d3.select("circle#" + neighbors[i]).style("opacity", newOpacity);
            d3.selectAll("line." + neighbors[i]).style("opacity", newOpacity);
        }
        // Update whether or not the node is active
        n.active = active;
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It is working now. It seems I need to go deeply into your codes and have some more understanding. I am new to D3.

Comment: One more question, please. What is the reason of using filter and map in the codes? May you please explain to me in a few words? What I could see that if you click on one of the other nodes, the blue one disappears. Any idea why?

Comment: @user2864315: yes, the code right now will hide the neighbors and all the neighbor's links when you click on any node. It is very general, so if you only want this behavior for one particular node, you can easily add an `if` statement so that it only applies to that one node. Also, I will add a few sentences explaining the `map` and `filter`.

Comment: @user2864315: I added a small feature that lets you choose the nodes that are clickable, so that in the example only the blue node (`"Node1"`) is clickable.

Comment: Could you please send me that feature?

Comment: I really liked both idea and style of this answer.