# hide nodes and children in D3.js using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I´m forking an excellent force directed layout (@eyaler http://bl.ocks.org/eyaler/1058611) with multiple options, and I would like to **hide a specific node with children using jQuery or D3+JavaScript**, not directly from d3 code using the toggle function. (this is important because I have an external button in the html code)

http://bl.ocks.org/carlos-andres/c3194c284763fde317b0

I tried commands like:

```
d3.selectAll("g#Avenger").attr("visibility", "hidden");

d3.select("g#Spathi").selectAll("*").attr("visibility", "hidden");

d3.select("g#Spathi").selectAll(this.children).attr("visibility", "hidden");

d3.select("g#Spathi + g").each(function(d){ console.log(d)});
```

It hides the node, but not the label and path.  I also tried:

```
jQuery('g#Avenger').siblings().toggle();
```

It hides all the other nodes.

**UPDATE**: I tried to use the solution here: [A d3.select... equivalent to jQuery.children()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956602/a-d3-select-equivalent-to-jquery-children) given from @Klaujesi and it doesn't work for me. I'm also checked another post, [How to display and hide links and nodes when clicking on a node in D3 Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249215/how-to-display-and-hide-links-and-nodes-when-clicking-on-a-node-in-d3-javascript) and I can´t get good results with that approach either.

Check the image; it hides node g#Spathi but not the children and paths

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You has `<tex>` outside `<g>` element:

```
<g id="Drone" class="node" ...
    <path d="M-8.378872.....city: 1;"></path>
</g>
<text dy=".35em" dx="9.45 .... city: 1;">&ensp;Drone</text>
```

must be:

```
<g id="Drone" class="node" ...
    <path d="M-8.378872.....city: 1;"></path>
    <text dy=".35em" dx="9.45 .... city: 1;">&ensp;Drone</text>
</g>
```

make `<text>`, `<g>` dependant

Comment: Hello @Klaujesi ok, this works fine for node+text but the childrens? how i do select all of them and hide? Thanks

Comment: To access child look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956602/a-d3-select-equivalent-to-jquery-children

Comment: Hello @Klaujesi I´m updating the code and run your suggested answer and not works.. thanks